# How to change application pool of site programatically depending on target .net version

Tags: .net, set, application-pool

I want to set application pool of site programatically depending on .net target version.Can somebody help me with C# code for this.I want like

```
for(each application pool in system)
{
if this pool is targeting .net V2.0 then set site's application pool to this pool
}
```

Comment: I think if you don't have the right target version configured, then the code won't execute.  Thus, even if you wrote code to do this you wouldn't be able to change it unless it already was the correct version.  Or are you planning to run this code from an external program?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ServerManager.ApplicationPools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager.applicationpools.aspx), should get you [started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), specifically I think you're looking for [ManagedRuntimeVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.applicationpool.managedruntimeversion%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)